# What does "if the rightmost column of the augmented matrix contains a pivot then the system has no solutions" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

What does "if the rightmost column of the augmented matrix contains a pivot then the system has no solutions" mean?

I thought the augmented matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Has a unique solution. Why does my book say that if the last column contains a pivot then there are no solutions?

Answer (score 4):

As I interpret it, they mean by "augmented matrix" the *full* coefficient matrix, where the equation
$$
\cases{ax + by = c\\dx+ey=f}
$$
gets rewritten to the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}
$$
I hope you can see that if *this* matrix has a pivot in the right-most column, then the system has no solution.

Comment: (+1) OH I see. I thought without c and f. Thank you.